# ANDROID / Error parsing a JSON object encoded string

Tags: android, json, parsing, string-parsing

my code receives a JSON object coded string from the server, which can be:
[{"logstatus":"0"}] or [{"logstatus":"1"}]

Then it converts this JSON (received as ImputStream), then I convert it to a string and later I want to convert it to a JSON object. But here it appears an error.
Here is my code:

```
public JSONArray getserverdata(ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters, String urlwebserver ) {   
  httppostconnect(parameters,urlwebserver);    
  if (is!=null) { //si obtuvo una respuesta    
    getpostresponse();    
    return getjsonarray();   
  } else {   
    return null;    
  }
}

private void httppostconnect(ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametros, String urlwebserver) {
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urlwebserver);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametros));
    //ejecuto peticion enviando datos por POST
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
  }     
}

public void getpostresponse() {       
  try {    
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    result = sb.toString();
    Log.e("getpostresponse"," result="+sb.toString());
  } catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 
  }
}

public JSONArray getjsonarray() {
  //parse json data
  try {       
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    return jArray;
  } catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    return null;
  } 
}
```

The error is in the function getjsonarray().

Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ?? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.

I have verified that the server returns a JSON with good format (which can be [{"logstatus":"0"}] or [{"logstatus":"1"}].

Also I've tried to use JSONToken but it doesnt work either.

Hope you can help me!

Comment: `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("[{\"logstatus\":\"1\"}]");` works fine, so the problem must be your String receiving. Check your data again.

Answer (score 0):

Please log out the data you received. My guess is that you are not getting what you think. That string looks fine and should parse fine. When you log out the exception, also log out the offending String, and you should see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a JsonArray from a String you need first validate if your String has the format need to do that.

You can do it printing your result string and test it [here.](http://jsonlint.com/)